# Nginx as reverse proxy does not send all requests

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

In a study project I create a web app with node. The node server is hosted in a virtual machine hosted on a physic machine that is isolated from the web by another machine that host a Nginx server acting as a reverse proxy. I noticed that some POST request sent to the web app reach Nginx (it is logged) but never reach the node server (no reaction of the server, not a hint in the logs produced by [express-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-logger). The most surprising is that the same requests could or could not reach the second machine. It seems totaly random, I mean I cannot predict if a request will succeed or not but if it do not I can try again until it work and it will work.
Here is /etc/nginx/proxy_params :

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
```

Here is the nginx file in sites-available :

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy; ## listen for ipv4
    keepalive_timeout 70;

    server_name 10patch.server.com 10patch;
    include error_params;
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /10patch/$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://raid2016.server.com;
        #proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

# Forcer le https
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 10patch.server.com 10patch;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

I do not know if I was clear but the problem is not very clear in my mind, and having to explain it in english does not make it easier.

Comment: Please edit your question to show a POST and the matching Nginx access log. Check the Nginx error logs too.

Comment: Ok a friend help me to find the problem. It was a 499 error of nginx caused by a change of page just after the request was sent. I moved the setting of window.location into the $.post callback in the client and it seems to work well